# How to remove repetitions of length 3 or greater in Pandas DataFrame row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which consists entirely of float values representing spatial data (basically a horizontal cutaway of a surface). Sometimes the sensor generating these values does so incorrectly and will repeat several values in a row. I want to remove repeating sequences of length 3 or greater while leaving the first value of the repetition and all other instances of the value (including sequences of length 2) where they are.

For example, suppose a row contains `[0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, ...]`. There is a 4-long repetition of `0.2` at the beginning of the row and a 2-long repetition of `0.2` at the end. What I want to do is remove every value of the 4-long repetition of `0.2` while leaving the first instance where it is, and do nothing to the 2-long repetition. So the output I desire would be `[0.5, 0.2, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, ...]`.

I know I can do this by just iterating through the rows and finding these sequences, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this using Pandas's built in functions or another library? The data files can be absolutely massive so I need an efficient way to filter out these repetitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `shift` + `ne` (not equal) +  `cumsum` to create unique label for each group of consecutive values. Then we group to find the size. You can then use `where` to `NaN` the duplicate values within each consecutive group if they are above a certain size.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2]})

df['grp'] = df['data'].ne(df['data'].shift()).cumsum()
df['size'] = df.groupby('grp').grp.transform('size')

df['data'].where(~(df['grp'].duplicated() & df['size'].ge(3))).tolist()
#[0.5, 0.2, nan, nan, nan, 0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2]
```

---

With the created columns the DataFrame is:

```
print(df)
   data  grp  size
0   0.5    1     1
1   0.2    2     4
2   0.2    2     4
3   0.2    2     4
4   0.2    2     4
5   0.3    3     1
6   0.6    4     1
7   0.2    5     2
8   0.2    5     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposition:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

data=pd.DataFrame({'vals':[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.8]})

#split data by blocks of consecutive same values
data['blocks'] = (data.vals.shift(1) != data.vals).astype(int).cumsum()

#count number of values in each block
blocks=Counter(data['blocks'])

def filter(block_id, nb_vals):
    
    #if one value in block, continue
    if nb_vals<1:
        return
    
    #if more, set values to nan except the first one
    else:
        indxs=data[data.blocks==block_id].index.values[1:]
        data.vals[indxs]=np.nan
        

#loop on blocks
for block_id, nb_vals in blocks.items():
    
    filter(block_id, nb_vals)
```

data has been modified:

```
    vals  blocks
0    0.2       1
1    NaN       1
2    NaN       1
3    0.3       2
4    0.4       3
5    0.1       4
6    NaN       4
7    NaN       4
8    0.2       5
9    0.5       6
10   0.6       7
11   0.8       8
```